# The cleanest way of filtering Interactors result

Tags: android, mvp, clean-architecture

I'm trying to implenet clean architecture in my app. 
I have `LoadItemsInteractor` that loads all items from repository and also I have `LoadItemsByIdInteractor` that loads items by id.

I have a method, that filters received items, and both interactors share it. I wonder where should I place this code. Options:

- `Utils` class with static method `filter`, both interactors call it before returning values to presenter
- Create abstract `BaseLoadItemsInteractor` that implements `filter` method and inherit both interactors from it.
- Create `FilterItemsInteractor` and pass the result of `LoadItemsInteractor` and `LoadItemsByIdInteractor` execution (from presenter or inside concrete interactor).

What is the cleanest way of implementing this?

Comment: In my opinion filtering and `findById` belongs to the repository. I never heard of a namingconvention that contains "Interactor" before. Is the interactor an implementaion detail of the businesslogic/modell?

Comment: @k3b On some sources they are called UseCases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unify both interactor in one, and through the filter send the id and the rest of objects you want to filter to send it to the repository, thus saving you repeated code. At the end loadItems is the use case and byId is a filter, it adds the id to the filter and unifies the interactor into one.

Answer (score 0):

The plain loading of something from some data store belongs into the circle of interface adapters and is usually called repository. All logic u apply to the loaded data belongs to an Interactor. And as already stated an Interactor can have multiple methods if this does not violate SRP.